# How to make RouterLinkActive got an access to RouterLink which is provided within ng-template

Tags: angular, ng-template, angular-routerlink, routerlinkactive

Is there any way to provide an access to `ContentChildren` which are inside `ng-template`?

If you look at [the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmc2ur?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) you see the issue - the `routerLinkActive` directive does not see any `routerLink` directives in the second row.

```html
<div routerLinkActive="active">
  <a routerLink="/hello">Hello</a> | <a routerLink="/blank">Blank</a>
</div>

<div routerLinkActive="active"> <!-- non-working RouterLinkActive -->
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="menu"></ng-container>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<ng-template #menu>
  <a routerLink="/hello">Hello</a> | <a routerLink="/blank">Blank</a>
</ng-template>
```

For understanding how the `routerLinkActive` directive works you can look at [the code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.x/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L82)

Comment: so the issue is known https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31930